# (ASP.NET) Button event not firing the first 30 seconds

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a weird issue where a **button's click event is not being fired for a while** (around 20-30 seconds) and then starts to work as normal. Refresh the page and I have to wait for it to work again.

**Please note this:** It works when run in debug on the localhost, the behavior described is only found on the server. I'm starting to suspect a server-side issue, but I don't have access to it and would need to pin-point what might be causing this to the people in charge of it (if it's indeed a server-side issue).

Any help to locate the issue is much appreciated! I stripped the page down to the most basics and this is what I have.

**ASP:**

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>   

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd)">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml (http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml)"> 
<head runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /> 

    </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Code-behind:**
    using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Web; 
    using System.Web.UI; 
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 

    } 
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.se/ (http://www.google.se/)"); 

    } 
}
```

**Config:**

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: maybe your server is compiling your code for the first time so it takes time. did you try to publish your website?

Comment: Can you test it locally (not from within VS) or on another server?

Comment: @DaveRook Not at the moment, but I may have to set up my own to get to the bottom of this. I was hoping someone else had run into something similar are could suggest what to look at in the server-side configuration.

Comment: @ogun I doubt it's a compiling issue, as you can see from the code it's so basic it shouldn't take that long to compile.

Comment: @AmadeusHein, I have had this exact issue with VS2010 but with an MVC3 site. You cannot rule out a config issue else where, so you really do need to test it locally on your machine via IIS. If it runs fine, then you've narrowed it down. Until then, the question is too broad for me to suggest anything else, I'm sorry.

Comment: @DaveRook My colleague set up the website to run IIS on the localhost (without VS), and it worked perfectly as it should with no delay.